# Dynamically set the length of td using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am looking for setting the td length value to 4 for one condition then set the length to 11 for other condition.

Since we cant access the javascript values in jsp, I am not thinking to set any flag in the javascript  function
I thought of using the hidden parameter concept to access, Since I am using a BTT framework which Doesnot suport that feature. that feature is also eliminated

Then Is there any other way in javascript that we can control the display of td or tr based on some condition

some thing like for 2 td based row

```
<tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    (Display this if condition true)
    <td length=4>
    </td>
    (Display this if condition false)
    <td length=11>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>

</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just let JSP print a Java side variable as if it is a JavaScript variable.

```
<script>var width = ${width};</script>
```

Imagine that JSP `${width}` prints `11`, then the generated output will look like follows in webbrowser:

```
<script>var width = 11;</script>
```

That's it. You can just use this in your JS functions.